# Javascript for simple menu expanding

Tags: javascript, menu

Hi I'm new to JavaScript and I want to code a very simple expanding submenu.

```
<div id="submenu">
  <ul>
   <li>
     Something
   </li>
   <li>
     Another
   </li>
 </ul>
 <div id="submenu-1" class="submenu-options">
  <ul>
   <li>Something-sub</li>
   <li>Something-sub</li>
   <li>Something-sub</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="submenu-2" class="submenu-options">
  <ul>
   <li>Another-sub</li>
   <li>Another-sub</li>
   <li>Another-sub</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

To be more specific, if I hover over something I want the something submenu displayed if the mouse leaves I want it to be hidden again... 
I know it has been asked a lot and there are many ways to do this but Google brought up too many unsatisfying answers.
I hope you can spare 10 minutes to help me out of my misery

Regards and thank you!

Comment: I think you should pick one of the JQuery menu examples you saw in your Google search and start there.

Comment: i thought about that too but all of them came with extra code and i cant devide the stuff i want from the stuff thats uneeded due to my lacking javascript skills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="submenu">
  <ul>
   <li id="1">
     Something
   </li>
   <li id="2">
     Another
   </li>
 </ul>
 <div id="submenu-1" class="submenu-options">
  <ul>
   <li>Something-sub</li>
   <li>Something-sub</li>
   <li>Something-sub</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="submenu-2" class="submenu-options">
  <ul>
   <li>Another-sub</li>
   <li>Another-sub</li>
   <li>Another-sub</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

if you are not using any library then you need to bind it something like this:

```
 var menuText;

  window.onload = function()
  {

     menuText= document.getElementById("1");
     menuText.onfocus = menuFocusHandler;
     menuText.onblur = menuBlurHandler;
  }

function menuFocusHandler()
{
document.getElementById("submenu-1").style.display="inline";
}

function menuBlurHandler()
{
document.getElementById("submenu-1").style.display="none";
}
```

or you can do this nicely and easily using certain javascript libraries that have APIs to do this easily.. some of these libraries are Jquery (the most popular one), Sencha etc.

Some of these libraries have extensions that have menu implementation etc.

Comment: with a few tweaks this really saved my day :D

Answer (score 0):

I have used Dojo for things like this with great success. Perhaps the [Menu](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/Menu.html) or [MenuBar](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/MenuBar.html) will be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this sort of thing easily with jQuery, take this drop down example:

HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li>Nav Item 1</li>
   <li class="dropdown">
       Nav Item 2
       <ul style="display:none">
           <li>Sub Menu Item 1</li> 
           <li>Sub Menu Item 2</li>
           <li>Sub Menu Item 3</li>
       </ul> 
   </li>
   <li>Nav Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.dropdown').hover(function() {
   $('ul', $(this)).show();
}, function() {
   $('ul', $(this)).hide();
});
```

Comment: i really appreciate it, time to dig deeper into javascript and jquery

Answer (score 0):

You do not need java for this just plain CSS will do:

```
li#submenu:hover div {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: i thought about that too but how do you hover display:none;?

Comment: when you hover a element (id=submenu) you can make it's children appear (id=submenu1 & submenu2). By the sub selector (div) placed after the :hover.